# Select subrange of an array-returning formula like GOOGLEFINANCE()

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function

In Google Sheets, [GOOGLEFINANCE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281) returns an array of values, like so:

[image: array of results]

The formula is entered in A1 but the result extends into other rows and columns. I would like to "select" (not sure what the exact term is) a subset of this data. For example, I would like to select only the prices, without header (so B2:B22 in the image above). And I would like to do that in one formula, without ever printing the full table.

I tried `OFFSET`, but it doesn't work since it doesn't recognize the `GOOGLEFINANCE` formula as a range. Conversely, `INDEX` works, but only returns one cell at a time,  so

```
 INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("TSLA", "price", TODAY()-30, TODAY(), "DAILY"),2,2)
```

returns "345.66" for example.

Comment: The linked question asks for just one cell, which is answered in my question (and in the post) by using index. Mine asks about returning several cells. But yes, they're related.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could use `INDEX` without a row parameter to return a column

For example,

```
=INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("TSLA", "price", TODAY()-30, TODAY(), "DAILY"),,2)
```

will return the second column fully. However, To fully manipulate the array, you can use  `QUERY`:

```
 =QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE("TSLA", "price", TODAY()-30, TODAY(), "DAILY"), "Select Col1,Col2 where Col2>355 limit 6 offset 1",0)
```

Here I've made the following conditions:

- more than 『355』(Remove `where Col2>355` if you don't need it  )
- Total  of rows =5
- the first row

Comment: Fantastic. I completely forgot about `QUERY`, but that works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: This just solved my problem. I wanted the closing price of a day and not the complete array. Here is how modified the formula into  =INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE(A2, "price", C2, 1, "DAILY"),2,2)  Here A2 - is my Ticker and C2 is the date